# How to know how many instances of the same fragment are there in the stack, and stop a new one while adding if one already exists

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to know how many instances of the same fragment are there in the stack, and prevent a new one from being added if one already exists?

Here is how I check whether a fragment is in the backstack at all

```
public boolean isFragmentOnBackStack(String name) { // Example isFragmentOnBackStack(CatFragment.class.getSimpleName())
    Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(name);
    return f != null;
}
```

Here is how I add them

```
String fragmentClassName = ((Object) fragment).getClass().getSimpleName();
    FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.root_fragment_container, fragment, fragmentClassName);
    t.addToBackStack(fragmentClassName);
    t.commit();
```

Now, the problem is, somewhere in the app, someone is adding a fragment at a time where it is not needed. I dont know when that happens, so I want to put some code in the fragment's onResume to check whether this is going to be the SECOND instance of the same fragment and if that is the case, to STOP the fragment from creating (not remove the old one from the backstack)

Comment: Does `name`and `fragmentClassName` variables have same values? They have to.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("name");
// If fragment doesn't exist yet, create one
if (fragment == null) {
transaction.add(R.id.container_id, new MyFragment(), "name");
 }
 else { // re-use the old fragment
 transaction.replace(R.id.container_id, fragment, "name");
 }
```

Comment: Someone is already adding it somewhere. I cant stop that. onResume, I want to  know whether there are instances of the fragment already added and if this is going to be the second one, to stop creation

Comment: I edited my answer above. I still don't understand why you have to do this check in the onResume method and not in the parent activity or fragment. Before creating it in the parent activity or fragment, just check if it already exists.

Comment: I guess there's a team working in the app, and all of them are really tight in terms of tasks, and non can talk to each other. If this bizarre situation is what really happens to @J.K., then this solution isn't enough. In **absolutely any other case**, I'd go with this one.